# suma de elementos de una tabla dinamica

Tags: javascript, html

Deseo sumar los valores de las filas de una matriz dinámica, pero al realizar la suma solo me hace el calculo en una sola celda, he intentado de varias formas pero no logro realizar lo que deseo, que es sumar solo el valor de las filas individualmente.

Cuando se realiza el pedido de la cantidad de elementos que contrendra la tabla se generan los inputs sin ningún problema, la cuestión es que al momento de realizar la suma de cada uno de los campos de la tabla me genera una sola suma y necesito realizar la suma por filas individualmente

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Suma de Zonas</title>
<script>
function calculo(valor){
var total = 0;  
valor = parseInt(valor);
total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;
total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
var total=(parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor))
document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}

function crear(){
var col = document.getElementById("cols").value;
var filas = document.getElementById("cols").value;
var tabla="<table border=\"1\" id=\"miTabla\">";
tabla+="<tr><td>Zona</td>";
for(j=0;j<col;j++){ 
    tabla+="<td>"+(j+1)+"</td>";
}
tabla+="<td>Total</td>";
tabla+="</tr>";

for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
    tabla+="<tr>";
    tabla+="<td>"+(i+1)+ "</td>";
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){ 
        tabla+="<td>"+'<input type=\"text\" size=\"1\" id=\"txt_campo"\" 
onchange=\"calculo(this.value);\"/>'+ "</td>";       
    }
tabla+="<td id=\"spTotal\"></span></td>";
    tabla+="</tr>";

}
tabla+="</table>";
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=tabla;
}

function crear2() {
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML="";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="cols" /> Cantidad de Zonas <br />
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="crear tabla" onclick="crear()"/>
<input type="button" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar" onclick="crear2()"/>

</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe identificar de forma exclusiva cada fila de la tabla para poder sumar los valores de los `inputs` en esa fila.

En el siguiente ejemplo utilizo el índice de ciclo `for` para identificar cada `tr`. Este índice se pasa a la función `calculo` que selecciona todas los `inputs` de una fila, suma sus valores y actualiza la celda del total.

Compruébalo:

```js
function calculo(trId) {
  var trInputs = document.querySelectorAll(`#tr-${trId} input`);
  var trTotal = 0;

  trInputs.forEach(function(input) {
    trTotal += parseInt(input.value) || 0;
  });

  document.querySelector(`#tr-${trId} #spTotal`).innerHTML = trTotal;
}

function crear() {
  var col = document.getElementById("cols").value;
  var filas = document.getElementById("cols").value;
  var tabla = "<table border=\"1\" id=\"miTabla\">";
  tabla += "<tr><td>Zona</td>";
  for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    tabla += "<td>" + (j + 1) + "</td>";
  }
  tabla += "<td>Total</td>";
  tabla += "</tr>";

  for (i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
    tabla += "<tr id='tr-" + i + "'>";
    tabla += "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>";
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      tabla += "<td>" + '<input type=\"text\" size=\"1\" id=\"txt_campo"\" onchange=\"calculo(' + i + ');\"/>' + "</td>";
    }
    tabla += "<td id=\"spTotal\"></span></td>";
    tabla += "</tr>";

  }
  tabla += "</table>";
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = tabla;
}

function crear2() {
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Suma de Zonas</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="cols" /> Cantidad de Zonas <br />
    <input type="button" id="enviar" value="crear tabla" onclick="crear()" />
    <input type="button" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar" onclick="crear2()" />

  </form>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás repitiendo ID de *inputs* y de celda para mostrar la suma, por eso es que solo toma la primera.

- En la función no envíes como parámetro el valor del campo, mejor envía el evento, porque es necesario volver a contar todos en cada fila, de lo contrario, en cada cambio se irá incrementando la suma, sin importar si el campo tenía un valor anterior o no
- Desde el evento, puedes obtener el campo que se modificó con [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) y, desde ahí, la fila con [closest('tr')](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- Después obtienes todos los campos con [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) por nombre de etiqueta y se recorren para sumarlos todos
- Al final, seleccionas la celda por su clase `.spTotal` y asignas el valor

```js
function calculo(e){
    // Inicializar total
    let total = 0;
    // Obtener fila desde el evento
    let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
    // Obtener todos los inputs de la misma fila
    let inputs = tr.querySelectorAll('input');
    // Recorrer para sumar
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        // Asegurar que se tiene un valor entero
        let valor = parseInt(input.value) || 0;
        // Sumar
        total += valor;
    });
    // Asignar suma a la celda, que se obtiene por clase
    tr.querySelector('.spTotal').textContent = total;
}

function crear(){
var col = document.getElementById("cols").value;
var filas = document.getElementById("cols").value;
var tabla="<table border=\"1\" id=\"miTabla\">";
tabla+="<tr><td>Zona</td>";
for(j=0;j<col;j++){ 
    tabla+="<td>"+(j+1)+"</td>";
}
tabla+="<td>Total</td>";
tabla+="</tr>";

for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
    tabla+="<tr>";
    tabla+="<td>"+(i+1)+ "</td>";
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){ 
        // Enviar evento en lugar del campo y sin asignar ID
        tabla+="<td>"+'<input type=\"text\" size=\"1\" onchange=\"calculo(event);\"/>'+ "</td>";
    }
    // Asignar clase a la celda que va a contener la suma
tabla+="<td class=\"spTotal\"></td>";
    tabla+="</tr>";

}
tabla+="</table>";
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=tabla;
}

function crear2() {
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML="";
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="cols" /> Cantidad de Zonas <br />
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="crear tabla" onclick="crear()"/>
<input type="button" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar" onclick="crear2()"/>

</form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Exactamente es lo que deseaba realizar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Disculpa la molestia, en el saco de sumar tambien los valores de las columnas y dar un total, probe utilizando la misma forma de calculo pero no me genera ningun resultado